# remove last space from end of each Phrase

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, expression

i have file like this

| Skor>Barn>Ballerinas,Leisure                |
| Skor>Barn>Sport shoes                                                                                                          |
| Skor>Barn>Sneakers,Sport shoes                                 |
| Skor>Barn>Leisure,Sandals                                                                                                      |
| Skor>Barn>Leisure,Flats                                              |
| Skor>Barn>Party shoes,Flats                |

i want to remove spaces and | from end of each Phrase 
how to remove it with out lose any space inside 
Phrase 
using regular expression

Comment: What have you tried and how did it fail? Show your code. Stack Overflow is there to help you with problems in code you have. We don't *code for you*.

Comment: You can do this using the regular expression `/ \|$/`. For example, try `myString = myString.replace(/ \|$/, '');` for each line. To learn more about regex I would check http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var str = "| Skor>Barn>Sport shoes |";
var deleteThis = str.lastIndexOf(" \|");
document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = str.substring(0,deleteThis);
```

```html
<div id='out'>

</div>
```

Comment: Questions like this should **really not receive answers**.

Comment: ok  | is deleted but still last spaces how i can delete last spaces

Answer (score 0):

You could use this formula in a different cell if the data is in Column A:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\| [\w\d\s[:punct:]]*[^ \|]")
```

And if you want to apply it to an entire row, add the ARRAYFORMULA:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A1:A),, REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "\| [\w\d\s[:punct:]]*[^ \|]")))
```